# Installing cvxopt for python - Where do I find libblas.a and liblapack.a

Tags: cvxopt

I've got a (what I assume to be) rather simple question regarding the installation of cvxopt on Windows. I'm following this "guide" http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html. But I've got stuck on the part where you're supposed to

> Copy libblas.a and liblapack.a to the src directory.

I think it's fair to say to I'm very lousy at these kind of things and that I've got no idea of what I'm doing. So I would be greatly helpful if someone could tell me where I could find these. I guess it has something to do with:

> make lapacklib && cp liblapack.a ..

and

> make && cp blas_WIN.a ../libblas.a

But I can't really make anything of this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Following that guide is long and painfull

Answer (score 0):

cvxopt is included in [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/). Even if you won't use WinPython directly, it's probably the easiest way to get cvxopt on Windows: After installing WinPython, you can copy the `cvxopt`folder from the `Lib\site-packages`directory into the corresponding one of your Python distribution.

**Edit:**
It's again available under the [unofficial windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the cvxopt 1.1.7 currently distributed with the [unofficial windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) has issues with the current winpython 2.7.6.4 (or maybe has issues on its own).  In my experience you could encounter many weird problems like code throwing math domain errors or arithmetic errors where things used to work perfectly fine on winpython 2.7.6.2 and the cvxopt 1.1.6 included there. I do not think that it is a problem with cvxopt 1.1.7 since it works fine on linux, rather of the specific binary packaging or maybe incompatibility of such packaging with the latest winpython.

If you are encountering such issues, maybe you can stay with winpython 2.7.6.2 that is the last version shipping a working cvxopt.